# How do I get the counts displayed on the bars of this ggplot barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a 'data.frame' called 'res' which looks like this:

```
name property count
john 7 3
john 6 3
john 2 3
tim 4 2
tim 1 2
kim 9 1
```

In other words, the name column has someones name. The property is a key referring to a parcel of property they own. And the count column is a column i generated that just has a count of how many properties they own. I am trying to make a bar plot to show how much each of them own (as a percentage of total properties). So far, I have the following:

```
ggplot(data=res, aes(x=reorder(name, count)) + geom_bar(aes(y=(..count..)/sum(..count..))) + scale_y_continuous(labels=percent_format()) + coord_flip()
```

And I get a bar plot with john as the top and longest bar, tim below him, and then kim. It's almost what I want but I would like to display the count variable inside of each bar (so on the john bar it would say 3) and im not sure how to do that?

So far, I have tried the following:

```
ggplot(data=res, aes(x=reorder(name, count), y=count) + geom_bar(aes(y=(..count..)/sum(..count..))) + scale_y_continuous(labels=percent_format()) + coord_flip() + geom_text(aes(label=count))
```

But while this threw in the counts, it seems to have exploded my x axis and compressed my bars all the way to the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `stat_bin` with `geom=text` so you have access to the hidden variables used to scale the location

```
ggplot(data=res, aes(x=reorder(name, count), y=count)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y=(..count..)/sum(..count..))) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=percent_format()) +
  coord_flip() +
  stat_bin(aes(y=..count../sum(..count..), label=..count..), geom="text", hjust=-0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: This did exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! It warns that "ymax is not set so adjusting position using y instead" not sure what that means.

Comment: great!  Apparently you can add `ymax=max(..count../sum(..count..))` to the `stat_bin(aes(...))` and the warning disappears.  I think it's a harmless warning